# Why does this code only work when i use 'x,y = y,x + y format instead of 'x = y; y = x + y'?

Tags: python, variables

I am working on Project euler, that's beside the point though. I am writing a quick code to print out the Fibonacci sequence. I actually have a different code for the project eueler equation, but this is essentially the algorithm I am using:

```
x = 1
y = 0
while x < 4000000:
    print x
    x = y
    y = x + y
```

This was erking me for awhile, this should have worked. I then researched a bit and found virtually the same code but in a tad bit different of a format. And it worked! The only difference was it put the x and y assignments into a single line, separated by a comma. So I tried it:

```
x , y = 1 , 0
while x < 4000000:
    print x
    x,y = y, x + y
```

Obviously, as I said, it worked. This is really bothering me as I can't figure out what the difference is between the two other than being clever and using less lines in the second one. I cant understand why the output is different. Why is the output different?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your first code:

```
x = y
y = x + y
```

You are actually assigning `y + y` to `y`. Since the value of `x` is already overwritten. And this is not you wanted right?

---

And in your 2nd code:

```
x, y = y, x + y
```

First `y` and `x + y` on the RHS is evaluated, and then the evaluated value is assigned to `x, y` on the LHS. So, `x + y` will not have any side-effect of newly assigned value to `x`, as was happening in the first case. So, your `y` will only have `x + y`.

So, it's just the case of `evaluation` of both those expression on `RHS`, before the actual assignment is done.

And yes, the assignments outside your while loop, will not make any difference. But the 2nd way looks more appealing.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that in the second version, when it evaluates `y, x+y` it uses the original value of x in the x+y.

In the two line version, when it evaluates `x+y` x has been set to y which leads to x+y being the same as `y+y`

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, which would mean the last line evaluates as y  = 0 + 0. I think if you replace the last 2 lines in the original with the last line in the working version, both versions would work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You reassign x.

Let's take a numeric example

Case 1:

```
x = 4
y = 2
x = y = 4
y = x + y = 4 + 4 = 8
```

Case 2:

```
x = 4
y = 2
x, y = y, x + y = 2, 4 + 2 = 2, 6
```

Hence in the first case x is 4 and y is 8, while in the second case x is 2 and y is 6.

Answer (score 0):

In the first version, the first assignment changes the value of x. This affects the value in the assignment on the next line. This means `y = x + y` is more like `y = y+y` because you already changed x.

In the second version, the two assignments are done simultaneously, so both values are updated simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

That's because after the line `x = y`, the second line (`y = x + y`) is evaluated as `y = y + y`. For example, let's say x = 2 and y = 3.

Then,

```
x = y          # i.e. x = 3 now
y = x + y      # i.e. y = 3 + 3 = 6 (while you wanted it to be 5)
```

On the other hand,

```
x, y = y, x + y  # this first assigns values to the right hand side
```

So,

```
x, y = 3, 2 + 3  # i.e x, y = 3, 5
```